# How to click on a Web-Element with attribute aria-hidden="true" in Karate UI

Tags: karate, ui-automation

I am trying to click on a web-element having attribute as aria-hidden="true" in Karate UI. But not able to perform click operation.

I have tried with click() method of karate but its neither clicking on element nor throwing any error.

Could someone please suggest me any solution here?

Here is the DOM -

DOM Snippet in which I want to click on the last div element having aria-hidden="true"

[image: 1]

Comment: try searching for other answers: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5D+attribute+ui

Comment: Hi @PeterThomas, thanks for the quick response. Actually I am not getting the exact syntax to click on web element by java-script in karate. If this is my xpath "//div[contains(@class,'selectFieldIcon__clear-indicator')]" then could you please suggest me that in karate how can I click using this xpath by java-script?

Comment: my immediate response is just use the karate `click()` command with the right locator. read the docs if needed, lets hope someone else understands your question and helps you

Answer (score 1):

you can try:

```
mouse('#someElement').click()
```

also attempt to debug by checking if karate can actually find the element using highlight

```
locate('#unclickableElement').highlight()
```